# Android adb shell error: cannot locate 'android_reboot' - Busybox not working?

Tags: adb, busybox

It seems that something happened to busybox in my rooted galaxy S2. For every single command that I run in adb shell I get:

reloc_library[1312]:  9098 cannot locate 'android_reboot'...
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

I tried to push another busybox, but I cannot push it directly to /sbin/ (read-only) and I cannot run adb shell to use the mount command to push directly to /sbin/ (because it gives the same error...).

I do not know what to do...

Any help is more than welcome, thanks very much

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just rescued my device from this situation by swapping broken busybox binary with this one from here http://nookdevs.com/Busybox

Make sure chmod to 755 and then push it to read-write directory, it was `/data/local/` in my case. Now you can run `/data/local/busybox mount …` in order to remount your read-only system partition and then replace broken busybox.